# Add columns to all tables in a database if the columns don't exist

Tags: sql-server, audit

I have to implement auditing in a database with many (50+) tables. I am looking to add the user name and the time when the user altered the record as columns to all tables. However, some tables have the columns already, so I don't need to add the columns to all tables. Assuming the column names are `DateTime_Table` and `UserName_Table`, how can I add `DateTime_Table column` and `UserName_Table` columns to all tables in the database if the columns don't exist?

I saw this [loop for Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152878/command-to-add-column-to-all-tables-in-a-schema) but I need help in SQL Server.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you only have around 50 tables, I personally wouldn't bother with a solution that uses a cursor. You can write a SQL query that looks at SQL Server object catalog views to generate the SQL code that you need to run to add the columns. One nice benefit is that you can easily review your code before running it. I think that the below query will be close to what you need for the `DateTime_Table` column:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(ss.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(st.name) + ' ADD [DateTime_Table] DATETIME NULL;'
FROM sys.tables st
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss on st.[schema_id] = ss.[schema_id]
WHERE st.is_ms_shipped = 0
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.columns sc
    WHERE sc.[object_id] = st.[object_id]
    AND sc.name = 'DateTime_Table'
);
```

I used `QUOTENAME` to avoid issues with special characters in table or schema names. Once you've tested the generated code and are confident that it is correct, you can simply copy and paste the SSMS query results into another query window and run them.

If you needed a more automated approach or needed to deal with many more objects, you could use a [cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) to find and loop through each table missing the column and [EXEC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) to execute dynamic SQL to add the column.

Answer (score 1):

We are also achieving this output using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. As Column Name is easy to understand for users to.

```
SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE dbo.' + TABLE_NAME + ' ADD DateTime_Table DATETIME NULL;'
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES Tab
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 
            'X'
        FROM 
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  Col
        WHERE 
            Col.TABLE_NAME = Tab.TABLE_NAME
            AND Col.COLUMN_NAME='DateTime_Table'
    )
```

Comment: I like that you're checking for the column name before adding, can you explain if I can add other column name checks in the same place or do I need to rerun once per Column Name

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tableName AS NVARCHAR(500)='NgayCapNhat';
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(ss.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(st.name) + ' ADD ['+@tableName+'] DateTime NULL;'

  FROM sys.tables st
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss on st.[schema_id] = ss.[schema_id]
WHERE st.is_ms_shipped = 0
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.columns sc
    WHERE sc.[object_id] = st.[object_id]
    AND sc.name = @tableName
)
AND st.name NOT IN ('__MigrationHistory')
```